# Display child unordered list in different DIV

Tags: html, css

I have an unordered list:

```
<ul>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>Products</li>
    <ul>
        <li>Fruit</li>
        <li>Veg</li>
        <li>Frozen</li>
    </ul>
    <li>Services</li>
    <ul>
        <li>Deliver</li>
        <li>Butchers Shop</li>
    </ul>
    <li>Support</li>
</ul>
```

Which outputs:

> - Home
> - Products
>   - Fruit
>   - Veg
>   - Frozen
> - Services
>   - Deliver
>   - Butchers Shop
> - Support

I am trying to display the child lists in a separate div. For example, say I was on the products page I would want something like this:

```
<div class="main-links"><ul><li>Home</li><li>Products</li><li>Services</li><li>Support</li></ul></div>

<?php
if ($_POST['page']=='products') {
    echo "<div class="side-links"><ul><li>Fruit</li><li>Veg</li><li>Frozen</li></ul></div>"
}
?>
```

Is it possible to do this in in CSS/HTML so that I don't have to manually split the child lists from the main lists?

Comment: As a tip: Your HTML-code is invalid. You can't nest new `ul`-tags as children of another `ul`-tag. You have to put them into the `li`-elements, like: `<ul><li>Value 1<ul><li>Sub-value 1</li></ul></li></ul>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you're trying to do is simply prevent some child lists from showing up, there is an elegant solution in CSS.

You can hide all child lists by using display: none and then apply a class to your body tag. That way you can selectively hide/show specific child lists in certain sections of your website.

For instance:

```
<body class="services">
...
<ul class="services-child">
    <li>Deliver</li>
    <li>Butcher's Shop</li>
</ul>
```

And then in the CSS:

```
.services-child {
display: none;
}
.services .services-child {
display: block;
}
```

Which would hide that child list in all pages except inside the Services section.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably achieve this by using CSS absolute positioning, to always point the active sub-menu to the left side

```
/*Make the sub-nav top/left position, relative to the position of this menu*/
#nav{
    position:relative;
}
#nav li{
    float:left;
}
/*The active sub menu*/
#nav li.active ul{
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:300px;
}
```

I'm sure jQuery could be used to create a new menu from the active one also. My jQuery isn't that great but perhaps something like this:

```
var menuhtml= $("#nav li.active ul").html();
$("#sidebarmenu").html(menuhtml);
```